# Changed light, when the new light is off the fuse go down

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling, light

I have changed light, it was quite messy 4 cables of each color so when I have finally put everything in and turned the electricity on again all worked, but when I wanted turn it off the fuse went down. Any ideas? Thank you

Here is the new light:
[image: New light]

Here is the old light:
[image: Old light]

Comment: I've edited your post to include the images. Please double check to ensure I've properly labeled the new and old wiring.

Comment: OK, what actually happened was you hooked it all up this way while the switch was off.  When you turned on the circuit breaker, the light was on.  (for a  reason lol).  You wanted the light off, so you flipped the switch.  The switch already was off, now it's on.  The switch being on tripped the breaker.

Comment: Thank You for editing, its correct. So shall  i undo it when the switch is off and try it again?